# Google ads remarketing label conversion

Tags: google-tag-manager, ads, google-ads-api

I configured the purchase tag in google tag manager

I also configured the remarketing tags:

add_to_cart
purchase
view_item
view_item_list

I want to use max performance

Should I use the conversion label of my purchase conversion action present in Google Ads for all my Google Tag Manager remarketing tags?

Should I create a conversion action in Google Ads for each remarketing tag and add a different conversion label for each remarketing tag in Google Tag Manager?

Or should I leave the field empty for each conversion label of each of my remarketing tags in google tag manager?

Please enlighten me

THANKS

I don't know how to fill out my conversion labels of my remarketing tags in my google tag manager to advertise google ads

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.